# DateTime.Parse not working on Windows Server 2012

Tags: c#, .net, windows-server-2012-r2

I have an old and heavy windows application where DateTime.TryParse(string value, out result) is used extensively.

The below code runs smoothly on Windows 7 and Windows 10.

// Below is done when the application starts

```
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("en-AU");

var success = DateTime.TryParse("20 02", out result);
```

// Above is just an example of one of the ways we have been using it.  Here success is true and results are -> `20/02/2020 12:00:00 AM`

But above statement returns false when executed on Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard.
Appears like Win Server 2012 has broken the 
*DateTime.TryParse*. Interestingly if I use `.netFramework 3.5` then it works in all OS. But we are on framework v4.6.2 (VS-2019).

Is this a bug in Microsoft OS or .netFramework 4.6? Is there any existing workaround for this without making any changes in code, maybe a .net framework patch, etc. Honestly, it will be difficult for me to make any changes in code related to this as its usage is more than 1.5k in the application.

Thanks in advance !!!

Comment: If it really is used in 10k places perhaps you should Find/Replace `DateTime.TryParse` -> `DateTime.TryParseX` and provide your own extension method (or similar) that handles this... or switch to a parse exact route. It's really poor to just sling two numbers into a date parsing routine and hope it can use one as the date and the other as the month for the current year

Comment: If you print out `CultureInfo.CurrentCultureInfo.DateTimeFormat.DateSeparator` just before the `DateTime.TryParse` - are they the same?

Comment: @Cairus Jard - We are trying best to not  make changes in code as it used to work in other Operating system. Defintiely something is wrong with Windows Server 2012 R2.

Comment: @Frank Nielsen - DateSepartor is  "/" on Win Server 2102 which is the same in Windows 10 where TryParse works.

Comment: Are your `windows 10/7` and `windows server 2012 R2` running the app on excat same .net framework?

Comment: but since the date separator is `/`, shouldn't your date also be formatted this way  `20/02`? else you have do create a Custom DateTimeFormat for your culture.

Comment: @Frank Nielsen - .net framework versions installed are same in Windows 7, 10 , Server 2012.   "28 02" is used to get parsed easily into "28/02/2020 12:00:00 AM"  on windows 7 and 10 without any custom date TimeFormat. But recently we have to deploy our application on Server 2012 where this DateTime.TryaParse has stopped working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe not the answer, but can you try this on your Windows Server 2012 R2.

```
foreach (var ci in CultureInfo.GetCultures(System.Globalization.CultureTypes.AllCultures).OrderBy(ci => ci.Name))
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0} ({1})", ci.Name, ci.EnglishName);
}
```

are you culture part of that list?

Read this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-lcid/a9eac961-e77d-41a6-90a5-ce1a8b0cdb9c

Or do this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/shawnste/locale-builder-v2-0-for-windows-8-1server-2012-r2-released

Comment: Appears like en-AU does not exist in Windows Server 2012 but on Windows 10.  This might be the root cause of it.

Comment: - Thanks a lot :)

Will update further if I was able to install the locale.